# invoking catkin_make failed

Tags: catkin-make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
kv@kv:~/catkin_ws$ catkin_make
Base path: /home/kv/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/kv/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/kv/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/kv/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/kv/catkin_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/kv/catkin_ws/build"
####
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/kv/catkin_ws/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /home/kv/catkin_ws/devel;/opt/ros/indigo
-- This workspace overlays: /home/kv/catkin_ws/devel;/opt/ros/indigo
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using empy: /usr/bin/empy
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/kv/catkin_ws/build/test_results
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests-2.7
-- catkin 0.6.16
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- ~~  traversing 1 packages in topological order:
-- ~~  - beginner_tutorials
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'beginner_tutorials'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(beginner_tutorials)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;genlisp;genpy
-- beginner_tutorials: 1 messages, 1 services
-- Configuring done
CMake Error at beginner_tutorials/CMakeLists.txt:211 (add_executable):
  Cannot find source file:

    src/add_two_ints_client.cpp

  Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm .hpp
  .hxx .in .txx


-- Build files have been written to: /home/kv/catkin_ws/build
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed
```

---

Edit:

```
kv@kv:~/catkin_ws/src$ ls
add_two_ints_client.cpp  beginner_tutorials
add_two_ints_server.cpp  CMakeLists.txt
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/225407/invoking-catkin_make-failed/) by [anonymous25787](https://answers.ros.org/users/25787/anonymous25787/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2016-01-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-01-30**:
So .. what is your question?

**Comment by [anonymous25787](https://answers.ros.org/users/25787/anonymous25787/) on 2016-01-30**:
I'm unable to proceed further with the given error.

**Comment by [anonymous25787](https://answers.ros.org/users/25787/anonymous25787/) on 2016-01-30**:
Error:
CMake Error at beginner_tutorials/CMakeLists.txt:211 (add_executable):
Cannot find source file:

```
src/add_two_ints_client.cpp
```

I find that src/ (add_two_ints_client.cpp) is present.
Even then I'm getting this error

**Comment by [anonymous25787](https://answers.ros.org/users/25787/anonymous25787/) on 2016-01-30**:
Please help me out.
I'm stuck here, unable to proceed further

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-01-30**:
Please add the output of `tree /home/kv/catkin_ws/src` to your original question. Use the *edit* button/link for that.

**Comment by [anonymous25787](https://answers.ros.org/users/25787/anonymous25787/) on 2016-01-30**:
I have added it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems that your problem is that you have created add_two_ints_client.cpp and add_two_ints_server.cpp in the `src` folder of your catkin workspace, while they should instead be in an `src` folder inside `beginner_tutorials` (i.e. `catkin_ws/beginner_tutorials/src`).

Moving your scripts in there should allow `catkin_make` to successfully build.

Also, make sure you have declared your executables in the `CMakeList.txt` file inside the `beginner_tutorials` folder. You should have something like:

```
add_executable(add_two_ints_server src/add_two_ints_server.cpp)
target_link_libraries(add_two_ints_server ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
add_dependencies(add_two_ints_server beginner_tutorials_gencpp)

add_executable(add_two_ints_client src/add_two_ints_client.cpp)
target_link_libraries(add_two_ints_client ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
add_dependencies(add_two_ints_client beginner_tutorials_gencpp)
```

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [Steven_Daniluk](https://answers.ros.org/users/25049/steven_daniluk/) with karma: 606 on 2016-01-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [anonymous25787](https://answers.ros.org/users/25787/anonymous25787/) on 2016-01-30**:
Thanks a lot.
It worked!!

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2016-01-30**:
Please check the answer as accepted if it solves your problem.